# Updating mongodb document inserts another new document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

After executing this doesn't update the existing document instead inserts a new document of updated content. tried many times passed another property upsert:false to updateOne menthod but didnt work..

```
       class Product {
         constructor(title,img,offerprice,actualprice,description,id){
           this.title = title
           this.img = img
           this.offerprice = offerprice
           this.actualprice = actualprice
           this.description = description
           this._id = id ? new mongodb.ObjectId(id) : null
       }
        save(){
            const db = getDb();
         let Opr;
           if(this._id){
          Opr = db.collection('products').updateOne({ _id:this._id},{
          $set:this
            })
         }
        else{

      Opr = db.collection('products').insertOne(this)

        }
       return Opr.then(result => {
       console.log(result)
      })
       .catch(err => console.log(err));

        }
```

Comment: `db.collection('products').updateOne({_id:this._id}, {$set:this}, {upsert:true}, (err,res)=>{...` this should work for sure, can you console.log `this` object?

Comment: Yes it's an object

Comment: I tried with upsert:true but didn't work

Comment: Same happens inserts a new document instead of updating existing one.

Comment: I would suggest you to try updating document from the console with the same command, simply open mongo, change database with command `use dbname` and type `db.[dbname].updateOne...`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you For Helping. :) i made a mistake in passing wrong id as parameter.. now its working fine..
https://avrbrands.herokuapp.com